# Sinatra Session Caching

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra, rack

I'm having a little trouble understanding how to get Sinatra to cache sessions.  This problem manifests itself when I fire up more than one application instance (ala Puma or multiple Thins).

I'm asking Sinatra (1.4) to use sessions like this:

```
 enable :sessions
 set :session_secret, 'secret sauce'
 set :protection, except: :session_hijacking

 $connections = []
 set connections: $connections
```

I've left the `$connections` in there to demonstrate that this App is using server sent events, in case that has any relevance.

I am them using Persona (Mozilla) to support logins/authentication and am ultimately storing the logged in email in Sinatra's session with:

```
session[:auth_email] = data["email"]
```

Where `data` is given to me by Persona.

**What I can't work out** is how I ask Sinatra to store session data in a persistent store (ideally Redis) so the app can be recycled without losing session state (I've done this with Ramaze before with `Ramaze::Cache.options.session = Ramaze::Cache::Redis.using()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Moneta](https://github.com/minad/moneta).

The project's Github page gives examples of how to set this up and is extremely easy to integrate with Sinatra.